# Tag a lot of MP3s, but only the Genre

Tags: mp3, tags, id3

I have a relatively large music database that is absolutely perfectly organized -- except for the genres. I need a program that updates the tags for all those MP3s, but only the correct genre. Any other information needs to remain as it is.

Does anybody know a program that could easily do that? Windows, OS X, Linux, doesn't matter.

I have already tried the following:

- Mp3Tag: Does not seem to do this automatically for many files, only for a search query like an album
- MusicBrainz Picard: Will probably re-organize my entire library?
- MediaMonkey: Does that sort of thing only for albums and the search is horrible

To sum up, I want to do that all automatically, i.e. just select all my files and let the program do the rest for me.

Comment: So to clarify, you're looking for something that will do this *automatically*? This would mean fetching genre data based on the song/album from another source, such as file-name, folder structure or online. Could you clarify this in your question?

Comment: How do you expect the program to figure out the genre? Do you have a particular online database in mind? If you're looking for such a database, [WebApps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Well Musicbrainz seems to have the DB, but not an app for tagging :(

Answer (score 3):

MusicBrainz Picard tagger (http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardDownload) will look up many metadata fields fields for you. I'm not sure if there is a built-in way to get it to only apply the genre field and ignore the others. If there is not a way to do this yet, you might try creating a plugin or see if someone else from the community is interested in creating a plugin that does what you want. (http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardQt/Plugins).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It's in Python, so I should be able to write one myself, probably.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Amarok under Linux - select the necessary songs, press "edit track detail" if edit only genre field, it keeps the other fields unchanged.
AFAIK you can install Amarok in Windows too

Comment: Thanks, I know Amarok. The functionality you describe is available in any other MP3 tagging tool I know, too. However, I want to do that automatically - just select all my files and let the program run and tag.

Answer (score 0):

Media Monkey helps. It automatically IDs MP3 as best as it can and then tags them.

Comment: I said that I already tested MediaMonkey and it doesn't work the way  I want.